Perfect Pitch: How could we say what a note is without referencing it to another note?
This is kind of a piggyback question on one of my previous questions about “Perfect Pitch”. Most peoples response to my previous question “Are tones recognizable by themselves or only in comparison with another tone?” was that perfect pitch is being able to recognize a tone without comparison to external tones.
I am still in belief that Perfect Pitch is really just relative pitch. Relative Pitch, but just considered “Perfect” because of one’s accuracy. But anyways, here is why.
When we say a person has perfect pitch sure they're able to pick out what a note is upon hearing it or to quickly write and know what tones they are using, but aren't they just recalling that notes relationship to the others in their head?
In other words, how isn't a frequency not just a frequency without comparison to others that are lower and higher? Same thing with color. Color is just color and they're only different in comparison to one another.

As with some of your other questions, it's unclear how much this is about semantics and philosophy, and how much it's about mechanism and practicality. I think what you're getting at is a semantics/philosophy point: pitches, as a concept, exist only by comparison. If sound waves somehow could vibrate only at 440 Hz, there would be no such concept as pitch; we would call it sound. But as a philosophical observation, this has little bearing on the neurological mechanism of pitch identification; it's just a point to make about our terminology.

Several years ago I took a music course. The instructor was an older woman who told us that she had perfect pitch, but that lately it had become a half step flat.

Voting to close as unclear in its current state. Right now, this is a question about semiotics or about the neurological mechanisms of recognition is equally applicable to any non-musical topic, like recognizing faces or shapes or smells, and it's getting confused with a question about the abstract concept of pitch.

This question suggests that either the asker has never met someone with perfect pitch or else needs to discuss the issue with someone with a neurology background, which is beyond the scope of this site.

Is your question "how pitch perception differs from color perception"? If so, please rewrite it this way, otherwise this looks like 3 questions in one.

Everything is, or can be relative. Obviously there always is a reference, implied or by convention. For frequency, the reference is the denominator (specifically, for sound, in human terms, the "second"). For musical pitch it's the convention of equal temperament and the notes known in the chromatic scale based on it. Since sound perception uses real positive fractions (therefore based on numbers greater than 0 as numerators and denominators) and they obviously have a reference (the time), they can be considered relative. But that's not the point. The convention is quite clear.

Besides, it's interesting that you seem to fixate on wanting a 100% absolute definition about something that you express as relative by definition to begin with. If you want to describe something that you "know" as relative, the definition itself is probably relative by its own nature. Then again, that's philosophy, therefore, as interesting as it may be, pointless to discuss here.

How is this question different from your earlier question Perfect Pitch: Are tones recognizable by themselves or only in comparison with another tone?  I have been ignoring this one because I thought it was the earlier one, so I thought that I had already answered it.

"I am still in belief that Perfect Pitch is really just relative pitch. Relative Pitch, ... aren't they just recalling that notes relationship to the others in their head?": No; they're identifying the note because they hear different pitch classes as having distinct identities.  Knowing that A is a major second above G is a separate skill.  If you still don't believe this, seek out some people with perfect pitch and talk to them about their experiences.  I even met someone one with perfect pitch who had had no musical training.  He certainly wasn't using interval relationships.

The difference is that a person who has perfect pitch has those notes in their head on-demand, without ever needing to be reminded, and their brains get so fast at recognizing those 12 pitch classes that they conceptualize it as just "hearing a G#", the same way you might "see a yellow hue". They are their own set of reference pitches.
People without it can't "hear a G#" without recently hearing some other known pitch to compare it to; to continue the analogy, a colourblind person might know a certain flower is yellow by comparing it to the color of their shirt (that's probably not accurate but you get the idea), but that's not the same as "seeing the yellow hue". a person who sees in color recognizes a yellow flower without needing to  compare it to anything external; they are their own set of reference colors.

If you think in terms of the three primary colors of light - red, green and blue - those are picked up by three different optical sensing cells in your eyes. In that way you don't have to learn the names of those colors in order to see that they are different from each other, and you don't have to remember one color to distinguish it from another because they are completely different sensing inputs.
Like if you hit your toe against something and hit your head against something else - you don't have to compare those sensory inputs against each other to find out if it was the head or the toe that's hurting. You just know because it's arriving in your mind through two different sensing channels.
Now, if you look at the way the cochlea senses sound in your ear, the way it is shaped actually spreads out the spectrum of frequencies, so that individual  hair cells and their connected nerves each sense their own frequency. In that way, when you hear a 440 Hz A, it's always the same nerve fibres that are sensing that particular note. For some unknown reason, some people are more able to sense that particular note very accurately in their perception of sound, and most other people perceive it rather less accurately.
To name a given note - yes, you have to learn that that particular perception is called an 'A'. But I will not agree that it's just a kind of relative pitch based on a comparison to the memory of a pitch.
The way you ask your question seems a little like you imagine the human memory as a recording device that can play back note frequencies so you can compare those with the sound you hear. That's not how the brain works.
As others write, people report that their perception of perfect pitch can change through their life. That makes perfect sense since our organs, including the cochlea, continue to grow and change through our life.
Interestingly, a very recent article just came out, that many people have more accurate perfect pitch than most of us realize:
https://news.ucsc.edu/2024/08/earworms-music-memory-perfect-pitch.html

Interestingly enough, the sense that keeps track of where your head and toes are - and therefore helps out with determining whether it's your head or toe that hurts - is not the same sense as your sense of touch.

The article you linked to is probably linked to the Levitin Effect, but not perfect/absolute pitch. The people in the study notably couldn't name any of the notes in their earworms accurately (along the lines of "what's the first note of the chorus of 'Oops! I Did It Again'? G#? B? Dang, if only I knew"), so they didn't have perfect pitch.

Most of us recognise colours, people's voices, smells, and several other thigs of similar ilk, without any reference to known colours, voices, smells. That's something we learn as we develop. But absolute pitch takes this to a far tighter degree.
It would appear that those with ap are born with it, unlike being born to recognise colours, voices, etc. It's only when they also have the ability to hang a label (pitch) on a sound that it becomes recognisable as ap.
There are several other similar questions with interesting answers already on this site, well worth a perusal.
An interesting (to me, at least) phenomenon is my tinnitus, which enables me to pitch a C note pretty accurately 95% of the time. That though, doesn't endow me with ap., not sure at all what it could/would/should be labelled.
But, the few folk I've met with ap haven't needed to go through a double process of hearing a note, (or any sound for that matter), and referring it to a remembered sound stored somewhere deep in their memory. It's instantaneous.
The fact that concert pitch moving over time is also interesting, and has also been covered on this site.


I am still in belief that Perfect Pitch is really just relative pitch.
Relative Pitch, but just considered “Perfect” because of one’s
accuracy.

Let's see if we can find some truth in that belief!   Yes, a person who had never previously heard and named pitches, a person with no musical background whatsoever, would be most unlikely to hear a pitch and be able to say 'That's B flat!" (or whatever).  There must be SOME element of memory involved.
But people with Perfect Pitch don't need to have heard a reference pitch that day, that week, or even that year!   (Or do they?  Does Perfect Pitch deteriorate without use?)   But anyway, it's well-established that there are people who can name a pitch without having recently heard a reference.   If it's a memory thing, it's very long-term memory!
You mention colour.   Colours are also interesting.   If you wake up in a forest, surrounded only by trees etc., does a yellow tiger have to appear before you can recognise your surroundings as green?   I don't think so.  You have 'perfect pitch' for colours.  But look at this picture.  Do  you NOT see this Coke can as red?
It’s weird because there is no red at all in the picture. It’s your brain filling in what it assumes is there. It sees 'not blue' and sort of overshoots to its complementary colour.
Zoom in and you’ll see it’s just blue, black and white.

How about this one?  I think you need to zoom right out to see the...  other colour...  but most people agree it's there!



the optical illusion doesn't work for me, and 2) it's not really clear to me what point it's making. Is it just "we can remember the color red even when we're not prompted by actively seeing it"?


I'm surprised this question has been dignified by three answers when the same points can be made about any kind of recognition and identification. If I recognize my spouse's face, do I do so only by comparing against all the faces that are not theirs? Do I recognize the Eiffel Tower, or a square, or the cry of a red-tailed hawk, or the smell of cinnamon, or any other phenomena that attach sensory input to a concept, that way? Any answer that takes the question seriously dives deeply into semiotics and neurology, but the casual answer seems to be "no, we recognize positively, not negatively."

If someone only ever heard one pitch or saw one color then wouldn’t they have nothing to compare it against? if so, then it would just be considered sound or color, and not necessarily a “different sound” or “different color”. But yes, thats exactly what I mean. A person with “perfect pitch” I am thinking just has extremely good memory and the ability to compare those tones easier than others are. It seems that with color it easier to remember because we always see color against each other, but we dont always hear sound against each other.

@lecifier Saying they have extremely good memory is perhaps a very simplified way of saying it. But we evolved (for good reasons) the ability to categorise colours, but not pitches. We don't say someone who can recognise all colours and describe the in-between hues as having a really good memory, it's built in to most peoples brains. And it's not that those with perfect pitch have a really good memory, at least not in the typically sense of memory. They never lost the 'pitch' neural connections in infancy and hence can effortlessly categorise pitches in the same same way most do colour.

Imagine seeing red for the first time, cycling round other colours then back to red. Most poses the innate ability to recognise when it returns. Of course there needs to be contrast, but only to differentiate the colours. Most could not do this with pitch, even before learning the note names. Certainly not if the time was long enough between hearing the 2 similar pitches. It's simply that most lack (or have lost) the hard-coded neural pathways stimulated by our auditory system required to identify pitches, but we do have this for colours. It's not what you would typically describe as memory.

@AndyBonner Try the coke can zoomed quite small, maybe with your eyes half closed.  Most people manage to get it.   It addresses the OP's idea that 'Color is just color and they're only different in comparison to one another.'.

@Lecifer Philosophical musings would be fun to pursue in the chat room. But there's still a logical fallacy in yours. Comparing the notion of a world with only one pitch with our reality is an exercise in semiotics and concepts, and has nothing to do with practical mechanisms of recognition. Just because the conceptual grouping "fish" is made up of many species is no reason, when faced with a goldfish, that I have to conceptualize or visualize a largemouth bass or shark in order to recognize the goldfish.

@OwenM I think you are confusing the ability to name colors or pitches with the ability to perceive them as different, although both abilities needs training for any human, but only the naming part would require a good memory as far as I know. If you look at how we train toddlers in discerning colors, compared to how we train them discerning pitch, a lot more weight are put into naming and working with colors, but singing and listening to music not so much. A lot of that is more about culture than how we evolved, and I see no evolutionary reason that colors should be more important than sound.

@hlynbech No, I'm aware of the difference, the limited length of a comment meant I was probably unclear. Note that in most of the comment I was trying to detach the sensory inputs from memory, I am clear that it's only the naming part that requires what we would typically call memory. I am saying this refutes the OP's hypothesis. Re evolution, the ability to discern colours absolutely to recognise different foods / dangers etc. is likely more useful than being able to detect pitches absolutely. Our good relative pitch seems enough to recognise voices, moods, environmental sounds etc.
